# How to start a different browser or several browsers using Gulp serve?

Tags: gulp, serve

I am working with Gulp and it always opens my default browser on serve. 
Am I able to define the browser I would like to use or several browsers?

Answer (score 2):

can be done on creating a gulp task:

```
gulp.task('serve:windows', ['typescripts', 'watch'], function ()
{
   browserSyncInit([path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve'), conf.paths.src],["google chrome", "firefox", "opera", "iexplore"]);
});
```

now you can call it like this: 
gulp serve:windows

It will start several browsers....